# No default proposals en JSF

Tags: java, jsf, eclipse

Me gustaría averiguar como conseguir mostrar en un `jsf` proposiciones de código para valores existentes en el código java del bean de la vista. Estoy utilizando `eclipse Luna`.

Para etiquetas `jsf` y sus tags si me da proposiciones, pero para lo que comento del código java aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve trabajando en un proyecto que si tenía esta ayuda y me ahorraba mucho tiempo y ahora no soy capaz de reproducirla. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?.

Actualización:

Por un lado tengo que mi versión de java de `javaServerFaces` no es la misma y por otro que solo me deja meter la librería de mojarra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización:

Tengo añadido `jsf`, `api` e `impl` en el faces servlet.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: usas Eclipse? los ficheros en los que quieres autocompletar son `.xhtml`?

Comment: Si. Eclipse y xhtml.

Comment: Lo más sencillo que he visto al respecto es utilizar jboss tools. Instala ese plugin y listo.

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preferencias > General > Content Types > Texto > JSP > Añadir (xhtml)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto va a hacer que eclipse trate los ficheros xhtml como jsp, por lo que autocompletara cualquier etiqueta que tenga definida en el formato `.tld`, (`<h:` y `<f` funcionarán.

[FUENTE (ingles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136218/eclipse-autocomplete-content-assist-with-facelets-jsf-and-xhtml)

---

Asi, por eso, no vas a resolver todos tus problemas, para el autocompletado de los facelets, es un poco más complejo, pero [MKYONG tiene un tutorial en 3 pasos](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/eclipse-ide-xhtml-code-assist-is-not-working-for-jsf-tag/) muy útil:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El paso 2 es el importante:**

- Tienes que crear una libreria de usuario como en la imagen.
- incluir la API de JSF y su libreria de implementacion.

> son los archivos **`jsf-api-xxx.jar`** y **`jsf-impl-xxx.jar`**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto que comenta ya lo habia visto y he intentado hacerlo en alguna ocasión pero hay pequeñas variaciones que hacen que no termine de cuadrarme la solución.

Comment: comentame en que paso concreto tienes el problema e intento guiarte.

Comment: he subido una respuesta con capturas para que veas donde me quedo. Gracias.

Comment: nada hombre, para eso estamos!! :)

Comment: Tienes las webtools [WTP](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/) instaladas y habilitatas??? si es que si.... cuando aprietas further configuration en Project Facets que te dice? Haces el paso 2 correctamente? siento no poder probarlo, no tengo ahora ninguna VM con JSF configurado a mano... :(

Comment: Si las tengo instaladas.

lo de apretar futher no aparece en la misma pantalla, tienes otra opcion en el menu lateral para llegar, como puedes ver en las capturas.

Comment: pero cuando aprietas el botón de añadir librería no te deja seleccionarla?

Comment: en el paso 2 pone que tienes que crear una libreria de usuario como en la imagen e incluir la API de JSF y su libreria de implementacion, que son los archivos **jsf-api-xxx.jar** y **jsf-impl-xxx.jar**, no te deja seleccionarlos? o que error te dá?

Comment: los acabo de agregar, dejo una actualización en la pregunta principal. El problema persiste.

Comment: y si añades mojarra seguro que no funciona?

Comment: volvere a probar, eso lo intente en su momento.